# Flyway SQL Server login failing

Tags: flyway

I've setup a sample app for Flyway using the Maven Plug-in. I created a sample database and created a login for the database and setup the connection in the plug-in configuration as described on the Flyway site; however, when I run `mvn flyway:migrate` the login keeps failing for some reason.

[image]

Here is the Maven config:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <user>flywayUser</user>
    <password>flyway1234</password>
    <schemas>dbo</schemas>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=MyDb;integratedSecurity=false</url>
  </configuration>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>7.4.1.jre11</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I'm able to log into the database using SSMS, what else could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
<url>jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=MyDb;integratedSecurity=false</url>
```

Enter actual server and port ?